# InAppBrowser: Can't use upload camera or photo from iOS 8.3 on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an external form that loads in an InAppBrowser instance.  We have the following code:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" name="image1" />
```

This works fine on an iPad (multiple variants), it works on all simulators, and I believe it worked on older versions of iOS on an iPhone as well.

On an iPhone running iOS 8.3 it kicks the user back to the Cordova app, which then becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I would recommend you to download and install GapDebug. After you did this you should be able to see the issue which kicks the user back. There are some weird issues currently with 8.3. Give us the error message and we're going to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: I think I've seen this bug since iOS 8, but search the issue on the cordova jira and if you don't find it open a new one https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB